# Regex: Repeated Capturing Groups without Global Flag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to recognise and process musical chord notation within text. In doing so, I've ended up trying to match a set of repeating patterns, but instead only the last matched instance appears in the returned array.

```
"Amaj13#11".match(/([a-g][#|b]?)(?:(maj|m|sus|dim|#|b)?(\d+))*/i)

// Expected
["Amaj13#11", "A", "maj", "13", "#", "11"]

// Actual
["Amaj13#11", "A", "#", "11"]
```

The group that should be capturing the other terms is: `(?:(maj|m|sus|dim|#|b)?(\d+))*`.

As I understand it, this is because without the global flag is not present, when I add it it correctly extracts and matches the correct parts and returns the string `"Amaj13#11"`, which puts me back to square one.

How can I either use the global flag and have the returned components in an array, or repeat a capturing group without it?

Some example inputs and desired output.

```
"C#m9#5" // ["C#", "m", "9", "#", "5"]
"Bsus2" // ["B", "sus", "2"]
"Db#11" // ["Db", "#", "11"]
"Fmaj6b2" // ["F", "maj", "6", "b", "2"]
```

Comment: You cannot "reuse" a capture group: see the *Generating New Capture Groups Automatically* section in http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html Also, I believe by `[#|b]` you mean `[#b]`. Can you add some sample input/requirements to find another way of doing what you want?

Comment: Updated with examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun question because although it seems to challenges javascript, it has a simple answer.

The approach I suggest is to forget capture groups and try splitting instead. But Javascript does not have lookbehinds (useful in specifying split delimiters), and as far as I know it does not have an option to split a string and keep the delimiter, as PHP does. This leads us to a two-step approach.

**First step:** Decide where we want to split. From what you've said, it sounds like we are looking at a simple regex like

`[A-Gb#]|(?:maj|sus)|\d+`

Please modify it to suit your needs.

**Second step:** Insert a marker at the split point. For this, we use replace:

`readyToSplit = str.replace(/([A-Gb#]|(?:maj|sus)|\d+)/mg, "$1[SPLIT]");`

This gives us:

`A[SPLIT]maj[SPLIT]13[SPLIT]#[SPLIT]11[SPLIT]`

**Third step**: split.

`result = readyToSplit.split(/\[SPLIT\]/m);`

This gives us: `A`, `maj`, `13`, `#`, `11`

You may have to adjust the tokens, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @DanPrince Is this working for you, or are you still wrestling with the question?

Comment: Didn't catch this comment, apologies. After getting the initial heads up on reusing capture groups, I went ahead and just implemented a lexical parser instead. Regardless, appreciate this approach all the same.

Comment: This worked for me. Needed to match multiple "ids" in a string. I split it, then filtered it, using the regex pattern as the delegate for filtering. Worked like a charm.